# Select union all - Select always zero for two fields

Tags: mysql, union

I wrote a football table program for my friends and they would really like to have some more statistics in it. But I'm stumbling about getting total wins and lose for the red and black team (W_S = win black; L_S = lose black) (W_R = win red; L_R = lose red)

Here is my schema and select:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a35/1/0

As you can see, W_S and L_S are always zero and W_R and L_R are wrong populated.

(schwarz = black; rot = red; tore = goals)

Thanks in advance!

## edit

whole [SELECT query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/814a35/37)

```
SELECT 
        `SpielerID` AS `id`, 
        `s`.`name` AS `name`, 
        COALESCE( (Sum(W_R) / NULLIF((Sum(W_R)+Sum(W_S))+(Sum(L_R)+Sum(L_S)), 0)), Sum(W_R) ) as 'rot_siegeRatio', 
        COALESCE( (Sum(W_S) / NULLIF((Sum(W_R)+Sum(W_S))+(Sum(L_R)+Sum(L_S)), 0)), Sum(W_S) ) as 'schwarz_siegeRatio', 
        Sum(W_R) as 'siegeCount', Sum(L_R) as 'niederlagenCount', (Sum(W_R)+Sum(L_R)) as 'spieleCount', 
        COALESCE( (Sum(W_R) / NULLIF((Sum(W_R))+(Sum(L_R)), 0)), Sum(W_R) ) as 'siegeRatio', Sum(Tore) as 'toreCount',
        Sum(Gegentore) as 'gegentoreCount',
        COALESCE( (Sum(Tore) / NULLIF(Sum(Gegentore), 0)), Sum(Tore) ) as 'toreRatio'
FROM 
        ( SELECT rot_spieler1 SpielerID, datetime,
          IF (rot_tore > schwarz_tore,1,0) W_R,
          IF (rot_tore < schwarz_tore,1,0) L_R,
          0 W_S,
          0 L_S,
          rot_tore Tore,
          schwarz_tore Gegentore
          FROM `kicker_spiele`
          WHERE datetime IS NOT NULL

          UNION ALL
          SELECT rot_spieler2 SpielerID, datetime,
          IF (rot_tore > schwarz_tore,1,0) W_R,
          IF (rot_tore < schwarz_tore,1,0) L_R,
          0 W_S,
          0 L_S,
          rot_tore Tore,
          schwarz_tore Gegentore
          FROM `kicker_spiele`
          WHERE datetime IS NOT NULL

          UNION ALL
          SELECT schwarz_spieler1 SpielerID, datetime,
          IF (schwarz_tore > rot_tore,1,0) W_S,
          IF (schwarz_tore < rot_tore,1,0) L_S,
          0 W_R,
          0 L_R,
          schwarz_tore Tore,
          rot_tore Gegentore
          FROM `kicker_spiele`
          WHERE datetime IS NOT NULL

          UNION ALL
          SELECT schwarz_spieler2 SpielerID, datetime,
          IF (schwarz_tore > rot_tore,1,0) W_S,
          IF (schwarz_tore < rot_tore,1,0) L_S,
          0 W_R,
          0 L_R,
          schwarz_tore Tore,
          rot_tore Gegentore
          FROM `kicker_spiele`
          WHERE datetime IS NOT NULL
         ) as ERG
LEFT JOIN `kicker_spieler` `s` ON ERG.SpielerID = s.id
GROUP by ERG.SpielerID
```

Comment: Why do you have 4 columns for winner? wouldnt it be better to have one column 'winner' being either 'schwarz' or 'rot'?

Comment: i want to tell whats the ratio of wins as red and as black, that's why i have 4 columns there. with 2 it works like a charm but i can't come up with a solution to calculate it easy from these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is somthing that might help you:

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN rot_tore > schwarz_tore 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END
) AS W_R,
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN schwarz_tore > rot_tore
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END
) AS L_R,
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN schwarz_tore > rot_tore 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END
) AS W_S,
(SELECT CASE 
    WHEN rot_tore > schwarz_tore 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 
 END
) AS L_S,
rot_tore Tore,
schwarz_tore Gegentore
FROM `kicker_spiele`
WHERE datetime IS NOT NULL
```